# rsyslog is not forwarding logs to elasticsearch

Tags: ubuntu, rsyslog, elasticsearch, logstash

I'm trying to configure rsyslog to send logs to logstash and then forward them to elasticsearch.

I have create a config file `/etc/rsyslog.d/60-output.conf` with the following content:

```
*.* @localhost:10514;json-template
```

and a template file `/etc/rsyslog.d/01-json-template.conf` with the following content:

```
template(name="json-template"
  type="list") {
    constant(value="{")
      constant(value="\"@timestamp\":\"")     property(name="timereported" dateFormat="rfc3339")
      constant(value="\",\"@version\":\"1")
      constant(value="\",\"message\":\"")     property(name="msg" format="json")
      constant(value="\",\"sysloghost\":\"")  property(name="hostname")
      constant(value="\",\"severity\":\"")    property(name="syslogseverity-text")
      constant(value="\",\"facility\":\"")    property(name="syslogfacility-text")
      constant(value="\",\"programname\":\"") property(name="programname")
      constant(value="\",\"procid\":\"")      property(name="procid")
    constant(value="\"}\n")
}
```

Then I restarted rsyslog service.
And for logstash I created a config file `/etc/logstash/conf.d/logstash.conf` with the following content:

```
input {
  udp {
    port => 10514
    codec => "json"
    type => "rsyslog"
  }
}
filter { }
output {
  if [type] == "rsyslog" {
    elasticsearch {
      hosts => [ "localhost:9200" ]
    }
  }
}
```

Then I restarted logstash.

When I run `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep 10514` I get this:

```
user@rsyslog-server:/var/log$ sudo netstat -tulpn | grep 10514
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10514           0.0.0.0:*                           5327/java
```

so Logstash is listening on port 10514.

To verify the elasticsearch input I run  `curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/logstash-*/_search?q=*&pretty'` but this doesn't return any results:

```
{
  "took" : 0,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 0,
    "successful" : 0,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 0,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 0.0,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
}
```

I'm using:

- rsyslogd  8.2208.0 (aka 2022.08)
- logstash 7.17.8
- elastisearch 7.17.8

How can I solve this ?

**Edit:**

I run logstash as following to see the logs:

```
/usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/logstash.conf --verbose
```

and this is the output:

```
sing bundled JDK: /usr/share/logstash/jdk
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
WARNING: Could not find logstash.yml which is typically located in $LS_HOME/config or /etc/logstash. You can specify the path using --path.settings. Continuing using the defaults
Could not find log4j2 configuration at path /usr/share/logstash/config/log4j2.properties. Using default config which logs errors to the console
[WARN ] 2023-01-01 18:50:48.417 [main] runner - DEPRECATION WARNING: The flag ["--verbose"] has been deprecated, please use "--log.level=info" instead.
[INFO ] 2023-01-01 18:50:48.423 [main] runner - Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"7.17.8", "jruby.version"=>"jruby 9.2.20.1 (2.5.8) 2021-11-30 2a2962fbd1 OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 11.0.17+8 on 11.0.17+8 +indy +jit [linux-x86_64]"}
[INFO ] 2023-01-01 18:50:48.426 [main] runner - JVM bootstrap flags: [-Xms1g, -Xmx1g, -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC, -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75, -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly, -Djava.awt.headless=true, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Djdk.io.File.enableADS=true, -Djruby.compile.invokedynamic=true, -Djruby.jit.threshold=0, -Djruby.regexp.interruptible=true, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/urandom, -Dlog4j2.isThreadContextMapInheritable=true]
[WARN ] 2023-01-01 18:50:48.689 [LogStash::Runner] multilocal - Ignoring the 'pipelines.yml' file because modules or command line options are specified
[INFO ] 2023-01-01 18:50:49.682 [Api Webserver] agent - Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600, :ssl_enabled=>false}
[INFO ] 2023-01-01 18:50:50.739 [Converge PipelineAction::Create<main>] Reflections - Reflections took 50 ms to scan 1 urls, producing 119 keys and 419 values 
[WARN ] 2023-01-01 18:50:51.350 [Converge PipelineAction::Create<main>] plain - Relying on default value of `pipeline.ecs_compatibility`, which may change in a future major release of Logstash. To avoid unexpected changes when upgrading Logstash, please explicitly declare your desired ECS Compatibility mode.
[WARN ] 2023-01-01 18:50:51.396 [Converge PipelineAction::Create<main>] udp - Relying on default value of `pipeline.ecs_compatibility`, which may change in a future major release of Logstash. To avoid unexpected changes when upgrading Logstash, please explicitly declare your desired ECS Compatibility mode.
[WARN ] 2023-01-01 18:50:51.438 [Converge PipelineAction::Create<main>] plain - Relying on default value of `pipeline.ecs_compatibility`, which may change in a future major release of Logstash. To avoid unexpected changes when upgrading Logstash, please explicitly declare your desired ECS Compatibility mode.
[WARN ] 2023-01-01 18:50:51.479 [Converge PipelineAction::Create<main>] elasticsearch - Relying on default value of `pipeline.ecs_compatibility`, which may change in a future major release of Logstash. To avoid unexpected changes when upgrading Logstash, please explicitly declare your desired ECS Compatibility mode.
[INFO ] 2023-01-01 18:50:51.658 [[main]-pipeline-manager] elasticsearch - New Elasticsearch output {:class=>"LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch", :hosts=>["//localhost:9200"]}
[INFO ] 2023-01-01 18:50:51.953 [[main]-pipeline-manager] elasticsearch - Elasticsearch pool URLs updated {:changes=>{:removed=>[], :added=>[http://localhost:9200/]}}
[WARN ] 2023-01-01 18:50:52.174 [[main]-pipeline-manager] elasticsearch - Restored connection to ES instance {:url=>"http://localhost:9200/"}
[INFO ] 2023-01-01 18:50:52.199 [[main]-pipeline-manager] elasticsearch - Elasticsearch version determined (7.17.8) {:es_version=>7}
[WARN ] 2023-01-01 18:50:52.200 [[main]-pipeline-manager] elasticsearch - Detected a 6.x and above cluster: the `type` event field won't be used to determine the document _type {:es_version=>7}
[INFO ] 2023-01-01 18:50:52.276 [[main]-pipeline-manager] elasticsearch - Config is not compliant with data streams. `data_stream => auto` resolved to `false`
[INFO ] 2023-01-01 18:50:52.362 [[main]-pipeline-manager] javapipeline - Starting pipeline {:pipeline_id=>"main", "pipeline.workers"=>4, "pipeline.batch.size"=>125, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>50, "pipeline.max_inflight"=>500, "pipeline.sources"=>["/etc/logstash/conf.d/logstash.conf"], :thread=>"#<Thread:0x332001c0 run>"}
[INFO ] 2023-01-01 18:50:52.380 [Ruby-0-Thread-10: :1] elasticsearch - Using a default mapping template {:es_version=>7, :ecs_compatibility=>:disabled}
[INFO ] 2023-01-01 18:50:53.026 [[main]-pipeline-manager] javapipeline - Pipeline Java execution initialization time {"seconds"=>0.66}
[INFO ] 2023-01-01 18:50:53.093 [[main]-pipeline-manager] javapipeline - Pipeline started {"pipeline.id"=>"main"}
[WARN ] 2023-01-01 18:50:53.158 [[main]<udp] plain - Relying on default value of `pipeline.ecs_compatibility`, which may change in a future major release of Logstash. To avoid unexpected changes when upgrading Logstash, please explicitly declare your desired ECS Compatibility mode.
[WARN ] 2023-01-01 18:50:53.186 [[main]<udp] plain - Relying on default value of `pipeline.ecs_compatibility`, which may change in a future major release of Logstash. To avoid unexpected changes when upgrading Logstash, please explicitly declare your desired ECS Compatibility mode.
[INFO ] 2023-01-01 18:50:53.188 [Agent thread] agent - Pipelines running {:count=>1, :running_pipelines=>[:main], :non_running_pipelines=>[]}
[INFO ] 2023-01-01 18:50:53.206 [[main]<udp] udp - Starting UDP listener {:address=>"0.0.0.0:10514"}
[INFO ] 2023-01-01 18:50:53.244 [[main]<udp] udp - UDP listener started {:address=>"0.0.0.0:10514", :receive_buffer_bytes=>"106496", :queue_size=>"2000"}
^C[WARN ] 2023-01-01 19:02:34.721 [SIGINT handler] runner - SIGINT received. Shutting down.
[INFO ] 2023-01-01 19:02:35.721 [[main]-pipeline-manager] javapipeline - Pipeline terminated {"pipeline.id"=>"main"}
[INFO ] 2023-01-01 19:02:35.798 [Converge PipelineAction::StopAndDelete<main>] pipelinesregistry - Removed pipeline from registry successfully {:pipeline_id=>:main}
[INFO ] 2023-01-01 19:02:35.873 [LogStash::Runner] runner - Logstash shut down.
```

**sudo journalctl -u logstash -f** :

```
janv. 01 18:50:32 rsyslog-server systemd[1]: logstash.service: Deactivated successfully.
janv. 01 18:50:32 rsyslog-server systemd[1]: Stopped logstash.
janv. 01 18:50:32 rsyslog-server systemd[1]: logstash.service: Consumed 1min 31.847s CPU time.
janv. 01 19:04:10 rsyslog-server systemd[1]: Started logstash.
janv. 01 19:04:10 rsyslog-server logstash[16111]: Using bundled JDK: /usr/share/logstash/jdk
janv. 01 19:04:10 rsyslog-server logstash[16111]: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
janv. 01 19:04:22 rsyslog-server logstash[16111]: Sending Logstash logs to /var/log/logstash which is now configured via log4j2.properties
janv. 01 19:04:22 rsyslog-server logstash[16111]: [2023-01-01T19:04:22,731][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Log4j configuration path used is: /etc/logstash/log4j2.properties
janv. 01 19:04:22 rsyslog-server logstash[16111]: [2023-01-01T19:04:22,740][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"7.17.8", "jruby.version"=>"jruby 9.2.20.1 (2.5.8) 2021-11-30 2a2962fbd1 OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 11.0.17+8 on 11.0.17+8 +indy +jit [linux-x86_64]"}
janv. 01 19:04:22 rsyslog-server logstash[16111]: [2023-01-01T19:04:22,741][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] JVM bootstrap flags: [-Xms1g, -Xmx1g, -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC, -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75, -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly, -Djava.awt.headless=true, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Djdk.io.File.enableADS=true, -Djruby.compile.invokedynamic=true, -Djruby.jit.threshold=0, -Djruby.regexp.interruptible=true, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/urandom, -Dlog4j2.isThreadContextMapInheritable=true]
janv. 01 19:04:24 rsyslog-server logstash[16111]: [2023-01-01T19:04:24,002][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600, :ssl_enabled=>false}
janv. 01 19:04:24 rsyslog-server logstash[16111]: [2023-01-01T19:04:24,940][INFO ][org.reflections.Reflections] Reflections took 56 ms to scan 1 urls, producing 119 keys and 419 values
janv. 01 19:04:25 rsyslog-server logstash[16111]: [2023-01-01T19:04:25,731][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] New Elasticsearch output {:class=>"LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch", :hosts=>["//localhost:9200"]}
janv. 01 19:04:25 rsyslog-server logstash[16111]: [2023-01-01T19:04:25,965][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Elasticsearch pool URLs updated {:changes=>{:removed=>[], :added=>[http://localhost:9200/]}}
janv. 01 19:04:26 rsyslog-server logstash[16111]: [2023-01-01T19:04:26,138][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Restored connection to ES instance {:url=>"http://localhost:9200/"}
janv. 01 19:04:26 rsyslog-server logstash[16111]: [2023-01-01T19:04:26,148][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Elasticsearch version determined (7.17.8) {:es_version=>7}
janv. 01 19:04:26 rsyslog-server logstash[16111]: [2023-01-01T19:04:26,153][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Detected a 6.x and above cluster: the `type` event field won't be used to determine the document _type {:es_version=>7}
janv. 01 19:04:26 rsyslog-server logstash[16111]: [2023-01-01T19:04:26,206][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Config is not compliant with data streams. `data_stream => auto` resolved to `false`
janv. 01 19:04:26 rsyslog-server logstash[16111]: [2023-01-01T19:04:26,256][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Using a default mapping template {:es_version=>7, :ecs_compatibility=>:disabled}
janv. 01 19:04:26 rsyslog-server logstash[16111]: [2023-01-01T19:04:26,276][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][main] Starting pipeline {:pipeline_id=>"main", "pipeline.workers"=>4, "pipeline.batch.size"=>125, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>50, "pipeline.max_inflight"=>500, "pipeline.sources"=>["/etc/logstash/conf.d/logstash.conf"], :thread=>"#<Thread:0x53d2107b run>"}
janv. 01 19:04:26 rsyslog-server logstash[16111]: [2023-01-01T19:04:26,466][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Created rollover alias {:name=>"<logstash-{now/d}-000001>"}
janv. 01 19:04:27 rsyslog-server logstash[16111]: [2023-01-01T19:04:27,008][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][main] Pipeline Java execution initialization time {"seconds"=>0.73}
janv. 01 19:04:27 rsyslog-server logstash[16111]: [2023-01-01T19:04:27,069][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][main] Pipeline started {"pipeline.id"=>"main"}
janv. 01 19:04:27 rsyslog-server logstash[16111]: [2023-01-01T19:04:27,127][INFO ][logstash.inputs.udp      ][main][9e1b2cf1672d2dd22a032525fa695bdf0d4d43163b1fd297f3b99f01f316ae38] Starting UDP listener {:address=>"0.0.0.0:10514"}
janv. 01 19:04:27 rsyslog-server logstash[16111]: [2023-01-01T19:04:27,157][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Pipelines running {:count=>1, :running_pipelines=>[:main], :non_running_pipelines=>[]}
janv. 01 19:04:27 rsyslog-server logstash[16111]: [2023-01-01T19:04:27,160][INFO ][logstash.inputs.udp      ][main][9e1b2cf1672d2dd22a032525fa695bdf0d4d43163b1fd297f3b99f01f316ae38] UDP listener started {:address=>"0.0.0.0:10514", :receive_buffer_bytes=>"106496", :queue_size=>"2000"}
^C
```

Comment: Please add logs as well.

Comment: @asktyagi please check my updates